# How to pass variables to jQuery click/onclick function without triggering function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My card game triggers the click event for all cards once the DOM is loaded. My code originally looked like

```
$.each(cardArray, function(i,value){
 var activeCard = $('<div class="cardContainer" title="'+cardArray[i]['name']+'" >'+cardArray[i]['damage']+'</div>');
 activeCard.click(doStuff(i,activeCard));
}
```

but after finding some other helpful responses to the same issue I discovered this was due to the () resulting in the function execution so my new call should look like

```
$.each(cardArray, function(i,value){
 var activeCard = $('<div class="cardContainer" title="'+cardArray[i]['name']+'" >'+cardArray[i]['damage']+'</div>');
 activeCard.click(doStuff);
}
```

Unfortunately this means I'm left without being able to pass variables I need. What are possible solutions or best practices here?

Comment: try something like this `activeCard.click(() => doStuff(i,activeCard));`

Comment: That's caused other issues but has solved my original issue and stopped them triggering- can you explain what that's actually done or how/why it's solving my problem?

Comment: you need to pass a function, not the function execution result as you did. my last comment is same as `activeCard.click(function() { doStuff(i,activeCard) });`